# JQuery filter checkboxes to show / hide elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the below code which filters elements by hiding them in JQuery using the  styles on the elements.  See my JSFiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/vy41zwch/4/).

My issue is that it I need it to show only elements that have ALL the checked filters listed in the styles and not show ANY of checked elements.

For example, if I select, "red" and "Coat" It should show only BOX A as that contains both filters.  Instead it shows BOXs A & B.

```
 //filter files list
    function filterFilesList() {
        var rows = $('.file-row');  
        var checked = $("#filterControls :checkbox:checked");
        if(checked.length){
            rows.hide(200);
            checked.each(function(){
                $("." + $(this).val()).show(200);
            });
        } else {
            rows.show();
        }
    }

    $("#filterControls :checkbox").click(filterFilesList);
    filterFilesList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the selector which is combination of all the filters

```
var selector = checked.map(function() {
    return "." + $(this).val()
}).get().join('');
$(selector).show(200);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/np0fxd6w/)

Comment: Yes that looks exactly like what I was looking for, thanks